# Google+ API does not return friends of my friends

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, google-plus

i'm developing a web app application with node.js, that can get the friends of my friends.
I followed this official tutorial (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/?hl=it) to setup my environment and my html+javascpt pages.
The code works and i can login/logout and get my friends info and my friends list.
To get the list i use this function:

```
gapi.client.plus.people.list({ 'userId':'me', 'collection':'visible' })
```

Now i tryed to change the id from 'me' value to a particularly id (taken from one of my friend), but the code doesn't work.
The reply from google to the request is:

```
code: 400, message: "Only allowed to fetch the authenticated user's visible circles."
```

the point is that my friend (owner of the application as me for google) was logged into the app and agreed the permissions before i sent the request.

Comment: Then I guess your friend has you in a private circle. Meaning that it's not a public circle, nobody can know that both of you are "friends".

Comment: Thank you for answering :)
I checked the list of circles that i "give" to the app, and my friend did the same.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the `people.list` method currently only supports `me`. The exception would be if you are using the Domains API with a Google Apps account.

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ team made a decision to protect users by preventing applications from retrieving information about a user's friends and network without their consent. As such, you can only retrieve a list of friends that a user has made visible to your application. Because a user cannot consent on behalf of their friends to get those friends' list of friends... your application cannot get friends of friends.